# Is there a web framework that lets you authenticate each link that's clicked?

Tags: web, authentication

I'm thinking of something that could be likened to a static site. But replacing the standard behaviour of  links with a JavaScript function that would fetch the content via an API (e.g. api.example.com/content?foo.html) and show the response on screen as if it were just a normal link.

The user experience is exactly the same as clicking a normal link. But what's actually going on behind the scenes is the content's being loaded dynamically. My motivation is to include an authorisation header on the API requests so that content is only served to authorised users.

I'm aware that there are many frameworks (React, Angular, Vue, etc.) that would let a developer *build* something like that, I just wonder if there are any tools out there that have been built on top of one of those frameworks with this specific purpose in mind.